# how to fetch document in file upload while editing

Tags: react-native

I have a form in which I am adding Profile data along with some documents uploaded, but currently it is not handled when I edit that Profile form, when I edit any Profile I am not fetching the uploaded document from data base can any one tell me how can I achieve this.